# different size/color vs different-sized/colored

Tags: word-choice, adjective-phrases

I am going to make up four sentences with them below.

> 1. These old different-colored (or different color) pencil crayons are very rare and valuable.
> 2. The different-colored (or different color) designs of these purses were created by a very famous designer two years ago.
> 3. The different-sized (or different size) dolls available in the discount section of the store have the same price tag.
> 4. The different-sized (or different size) stainless steel pots are made to satisfy different people's cooking need.

In my sentences, can I use both forms, with and without "ed", interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

Google can sometimes come in handy when we are undecided which [**noun phrase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) to choose from.
I searched using the British English spelling ***colour(ed)*** and the American English variant i.e. ***color(ed)***. I opted for *hair* because that seemed to give the best results.

[image: "different coloured" hair]

[image: "different colour" hair]

[image: "different colored" hair]

**881,000 results for "different color" hair**

[image: "different color" hair]

This looks to be the winner, but if we search through Google Books we find that the noun phrase is often split

> - The **hair** is a **different color** because of changes in the chemical structure of both the dye and the hair.
> - Many girls wonder what they would look like with their **hair** a **different color**.

So lets force Google Books to give us results for ["different color hair"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22different+color+hair%22&tbm=bks&start=0) closed in quotes

> - Some have **different color hair**, skin, eyes, and abilities.
> - Yet, with **different color hair** and with the Polaroid being so indistinct, there was no way that she could be recognized yet
> - And he doesn't look like them: he's got **different color hair**, different color eyes.
> - Well, in principle, that's no different than asking how children with **different color hair** (i.e., blond, brunette, brown, red) can come from the same parents who both have black hair.

Google books produced the following usages of "different colored hair"

> - We all have different colored eyes, **different colored hair**, different colored skin, and we have the most wonderful family.
> - Despite **different colored hair**, ethnicity and ages, the dancers had the same lines etched intheir faces from,too many parties, two much alcohol and excessive experimentation with recreational drugs.
> - Or the Wealthy Cattle Farmer who entertained a new girl with **different-colored hair** every Friday night.
> - There are different prices for **different colored hair**. (The 1913 newspaper article was referring to hog hair)

### Summary

As far as *different color (pencil crayons)* vs *different coloured (pencil crayons)*  is concerned, either form is acceptable. I would use the hyphen because  the adjectives *old* and *different color(ed)* modify **pencil crayons** which is made up of two nouns, if the adjectives were only two I might leave well alone. Compare

- These old different-colored pencil crayons (det + adj + adj+adj  + noun + noun)
- These old coloured pencil crayons. (det + adj + adj + noun + noun)
- These different [**coloured pencils**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored_pencil) (det + adj + adj + noun)

IMO, the best way to write *different + size*  in sentence 4 is **different-sized**, with a hyphen and the suffix **-ed**, as it helps readers to understand the text more easily. But i suppose you could argue it is only a stylistic reason, not a grammatical exigence.

(det + adj + adj + adj + noun + noun)

> - The **different-sized** stainless steel pots

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your detailed explanation.

Comment: @davidtrinh thank you!  I do hope this short answer was helpful.

Comment: What about (color / colored) TV @Mari-Lou A? Are they both acceptable as it goes with "pencil"?

Answer (score 0):

(1a) These old different**ly** colored pencil crayons are very rare and valuable.

(1b) These old pencil crayons of different ([various?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/various-different)) colors are very rare and valuable.

(1c) Different ([Various?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/various-different)) colors of old pencil crayons are very rare and valuable.

You may want to see the article here about [hyphens](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-a-hyphen?page=3) (especially between an adverb and an adjective) and the article here about [compound adjectives](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjE_dnslK3RAhWFGJQKHZgTCOoQFggqMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gingersoftware.com%2Fcontent%2Fgrammar-rules%2Fadjectives%2Fcompound-adjectives%2F&usg=AFQjCNHxiIHnu9sJXTpUYDba5cwRzn307Q&sig2=KA6L4R2LIiLI5KM8qAVnRQ).

By the way, I personally would use "various" because "different" begs the question, "Different from what?" while "various" answers the question, "Different from itself."

Did you need your other examples modified for you, too, or will you be able to extrapolate from here?

Comment: Can the answer to the question "What colour dress is your favourite?" be: "My favourite colour dress is red." Or should it be: "My favourite colour of the (maybe there should be the article "a" here?) dress is red". Or should I have asked: "What's your favourite colour for a dress/of (a) dress"? Thank you.